# golang - codecoverage always shows coverage: 0.0% of statements

Tags: go, code-coverage

I created one sample go project and created a unit test cases for the same (In Linux environment, go1.3 version)

When i ran `go test` the output would be

> PASS
>   ok      supported_db    0.201s

And i tried to perform code coverage for whole application by using  `go test -cover` command it shows

> go tool: no such tool "cover"; to install:
>   go get code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/cover

Also i checked the coverage while running a specific test case by running `go test -cover CouchDB_test.go` command it shows

> ok    command-line-arguments  0.158s  coverage: 0.0% of statements

please help me to run code coverage in golang.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try first:

```
go test -coverprofile=coverage.out
```

I then run, to see the result:

```
go tool cover -html=coverage.out
```

If the 1.3 version was installed through an upgrade of 1.1, 1.2, ..., you can try, as in [issue 110](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey/issues/110#issuecomment-30318453):

> I solved this by completely removing $GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/go.tools and install cover again:

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/cover
```

Answer (score 39):

[It helped me](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24570#issuecomment-478607461)

Just add `-coverpkg=./...` option if tests are in sub folders:

```sh
go test ./... -v -coverpkg=./...
```