# how to represent relationship between entities in Go?

Tags: graphics, go

There is a large project on Golang which divided into many packages. I want to visualize the relationship between its entities to better understand the structure of the project. The first thing that comes to mind - the dependency graph classes. How to build it?

PS:
And I want find all unused method's / structures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool closest to what you search (but without the diagram feature though) would be **[go oracle](http://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual)**

It can be embedded in:

- **[Atom](https://atom.io/)** with [atom.io go-oracle package](https://atom.io/packages/go-oracle)
- [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) with the [`waigani/GoOracle`](https://github.com/waigani/GoOracle) plugin

I also like to use test cases in order to [compute a code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604965/6309), which also helps to pinpoint unused methods.